# VPN breaks network connection after a period of time

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn

When I connect to my corporate VPN network everything works fine but after 20-30 minutes every time my internet connection brakes. I tried to ping URLs or IP addresses but **even the ping is not working**. The only solution is to turn off my wifi and turn back on again.

I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

I also checked the system logs and it seems that this log appears around the time when the network breaks:

```
gnome-shell[2573]: Removing a network device that was not added
```

What I have tried:

```
:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10243ms
:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search XXX.com YYY.com ZZZ.com
nameserver good-ip
nameserver good-ip
:~$ ping google.com
^C
:~$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Do you have any idea what can cause the issue?

**EDIT:**

I've tried it with ethernet cable also but the same happened again only a little later, after around 50 minutes.

Comment: Can you try plugging into ethernet instead of wifi? If the vpn does not drop, it narrows things down to your wifi.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question.